# Custom VerifyPeerCertificate in the crypto/tls package

Tags: go, tls1.2, x509

I'm trying to write a custom `VerifyPeerCertificate` to get the certificate even if CN and FQDN do not match.

I'm new to golang, so I'm trying to modify some code that I've found, and make it work but without any success.

So here is my code :

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "crypto/tls"
    "crypto/x509"
)

func main() {

    customVerify := func(rawCerts [][]byte, verifiedChains [][]*x509.Certificate) error {

        roots := x509.NewCertPool()
        for _, rawCert := range rawCerts {
            c, _ := x509.ParseCertificate(rawCert)

            roots.AddCert(c)
        }
        cert, _ := x509.ParseCertificate(rawCerts[0])
        fmt.Println("subject name is : ",cert.Subject.CommonName)
        opts := x509.VerifyOptions{
            DNSName: cert.Subject.CommonName,
            Roots:   roots,
        }
        if _, err := cert.Verify(opts); err != nil {
            panic("failed to verify certificate: " + err.Error())
            return err
        }

        return nil
    }


    log.SetFlags(log.Lshortfile)

    conf := &tls.Config{
         InsecureSkipVerify: true,
         VerifyPeerCertificate: customVerify,
    }

    conn, err := tls.Dial("tcp", "127.0.0.1:9007", conf)


    if err != nil {

        log.Println(err)
        return
    }
    defer conn.Close()

    n, err := conn.Write([]byte("hello\n"))
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(n, err)
        return
    }

    buf := make([]byte, 100)
    n, err = conn.Read(buf)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(n, err)
        return
    }

    println(string(buf[:n]))
}
```

I'm trying to get the certificate of a local server.

when I try to run the code, I'm getting this error :

```
root@mymachine:~/Tproject# go run test.go
subject name is :  dssdemo
test.go:50: remote error: tls: bad certificate
```

I've tried to mimic the [example_Certificate_Verify](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/x509/#example_Certificate_Verify)

Can someone help me with this ?

Thank you in advance.

**Edit:**

Mutual HTTPS is causing the : `test.go:50: remote error: tls: bad certificate`
But still, Is it possible to somehow return the server certificate ?

Comment: Notice that the error message says "remote error". It's the server that's unhappy, not the client. Presumably it expects you to [present a client certificate](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/tls/#Config.Certificates) but you have to check the server to know for sure.

Comment: Thank you, @Peter, indeed it's a Mutual HTTPS. But still I want to somehow return the server certificate (If I visit the website, I can see the server certificate)
When I go to normal HTTPS website, I have `test.go:52: EOF`

Comment: and EOF becaues my server was down, I managed to get the certificate.
But still I want to get the certificate even if mutual HTTPS auth is configured.

Comment: The [ConnectionState](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/tls/#Conn.ConnectionState) usually contains the certificate (chain), but I'm not sure if it gets initialized properly when this type of error happens.

Comment: Well, I've declared a variable outside the customverify function and then affect rawCerts to it. Then I retrieved the server certificate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This custom verification ignore all verfications:

```golang
func ipSCert(host, port string) ([]*x509.Certificate, string, error) {
    var ipcertchain []*x509.Certificate

    customVerify := func(rawCerts [][]byte, verifiedChains [][]*x509.Certificate) error {

        roots := x509.NewCertPool()
        for _, rawCert := range rawCerts {

            c, _ := x509.ParseCertificate(rawCert)
            certItem, _ := x509.ParseCertificate(rawCert)
            ipcertchain = append(ipcertchain, certItem)
            roots.AddCert(c)

        }
        return nil
        
    }

    log.SetFlags(log.Lshortfile)

    d := &net.Dialer{
        Timeout: time.Duration(TimeoutSeconds) * time.Second,
    }

    cs, err := cipherSuite()
    if err != nil {
        return []*x509.Certificate{&x509.Certificate{}}, "", err
    }

    conf := &tls.Config{
        InsecureSkipVerify:    true,
        VerifyPeerCertificate: customVerify,
        CipherSuites:          cs,
        MaxVersion:            tlsVersion(),
    }

    conn, err := tls.DialWithDialer(d, "tcp", host+":"+port, conf)

    if err != nil {

        return nil, "", err
    }

    conn.Close()

    return ipcertchain, host, nil
}
```